# How to automate creation of sections in mathematica worksheets?

Tags: style

I want to do a `for` loop to compute some values, create a new (sub-)section and print those values there within each iteration. How would it be possible?

Comment: [`CellPrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html?q=CellPrint) is probably the core function you'd  use in this case. You can find other helpful functions [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DocumentGeneration.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Do[CellPrint[
  CellGroup[{TextCell["i = " <> ToString@i, "Subsection"], 
    ExpressionCell[Plot[Sin[i x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, ImageSize -> 150], "Output"]}]],
 {i, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You gave very little details as to exactly what you're after, but something like the following should be a good start:

```
Do[CellPrint[Cell[ToString@RandomReal[], "Subsection"]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

[image]